# CAST WITH ALIAS AND CAST WITH coalesce

Tags: casting, alias, hiveql, coalesce

I am fairly new to Hive so please excuse me if I use any wrong terms. I basically want to convert/cast the output of

```
SELECT to_date(EXPOSURE.ETL_START_DATE) as EXPOSURE_Date_Key
```

into a string and also

```
coalesce(EXPOSURE_OPEN.open,0) as open,coalesce(EXPOSURE_CLOSED.closed,0) as closed
```

into a string too.

Please help. I have tried really hard for 2 days on this but couldn't solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could basically read the documentation, under "type conversion functions" and "string functions" _(e.g. printf)_ and "date functions" _(e.g. date_format)_  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cast statement like this

```
SELECT cast(to_date(EXPOSURE.ETL_START_DATE) as string) as EXPOSURE_Date_Key

SELECT cast(coalesce(EXPOSURE_OPEN.open,0) as open,coalesce(EXPOSURE_CLOSED.closed,0) as string) as closed
```